# What is vw, vh, vmin, vmax

Tags: html, css

anyone, please describe me about vw, vh, vmin, vmax. I found a tutorial for making a 100% height hero area. I found a CSS code, here i see they use height: 100vh;

What is it ? & what does it mean ?

Comment: Did you try googling? https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vw = viewport width = the width of the browser

vh = viewport height

if you set the height of a div to 100vh it will be the height of the browser window.